# Gather dependencies filtering by type

Tags: java, jar, gradle, copy, dependencies

I have a multi project set-up with a few Java sub-projects.
I would like to have a top level task for distribute the whole lot, for example "buildAll", which gathers every JAR for every sub-project, including all the third-party dependencies. What I have so far is something like:

```
task buildAll(type: Copy) {
    destinationDir = file("$rootProject.buildDir/")    

    project.subprojects.each { p ->

        from(p.jar) { 
            into("projects/${p.name}")
        }

        from (p.configurations.runtime) {
            exclude "**/project/**" //<- does not work
            into("projects/${p.name}/lib")
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, it creates a folder with the name of every project under the "build/projects" folder and includes all the JARs (projects and third-party), but some sub-projects have **Project dependencies** between them, for example Project A depends on Project B. So this task will get the Project B JAR and put it under "projectA/lib" folder.

```
-- build/
------ projects/
----------- projectA/
---------------- projectA.jar
---------------- lib/
------------------- guava.jar
------------------- projectB.jar <-- I don't want it here
----------- projectB/
---------------- projectB.jar
---------------- lib/
```

Is there a way of filtering this?

I have tried with exclude or include, but it seems that Gradle ignore them or the object is checking with is not the expected one.

Comment: Is this working?  Just wondering because the DSL for CopyTask is from () { } but it is being surrounded by project.

Comment: @AlJacinto small typo when creating the question...